# Floating-point division in bash

Tags: bash, shell, decimal, multiplication

I'm trying to convert whatever numbers the user inputs into 2 decimal places.
For instance

```
What is the total cost in cents? 2345
output: 23.45
```

this is the code i have so far

```
percentage=20 #cannot change numerical value must convert into 0.20
echo -n "What is the total cost? ";
read cost_in_cents
echo "scale 1; $cost_in_cents" | bc
```

I'm also going to be doing some multiplication with percentage, how can i also convert the percentage into a float (0.20)

Comment: What is the expected output for `1`, `01`, `12345`, `12.3`, and `123.456`? Can you specify rules which describe how to convert *any* number to a number with two decimal places?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `echo "scale=2; 1/3" | bc` sets number of decimals to two.

Comment: sorry when the user enters 2345 the code should convert to 23.45 if that make sense;
I also just wanted to know how it would be possible to multiply the cost_in_cents * percentage (20%) to give me the total in two decimal places.

Comment: You don't need to multiply by a float to get 20% of an integer -- you can just use integer math. Which is to say, you can set `result=$((2345 / 5))`, and then feed your result to `dc` or whatever if you want to make a float of it.

Comment: ...for a *completely arbitrary* decimal percentage, multiply by 100, then divide by that integer percentage, so `result=$(( 2345 * 100 / 20 ))` -- with variables as you like: `percent=20; result=$(( cost_in_cents * 100 / percent ))`

Comment: Anyhow. Right now, it's not clear to me what you're asking for that my answer doesn't already provide. Edit that clarification *into the question*, rather than adding it only in comments. (Examples help: "If my input is X, my output should be Y" -- you added that for the part we're already telling you how to do, but evidently not for whatever part remains unanswered).

Answer (score 5):

`awk` to the rescue!

you can define your own floating point calculator with `awk`, e.g.

```
$ calc() { awk "BEGIN{ printf \"%.2f\n\", $* }"; }
```

now you can call

```
$ calc 43*20/100
```

which will return

```
8.60
```

Comment: How can I pass variables into this function?

Comment: pass as arguments, for example on command line `$ a=4; calc $a^2` will return 16.0

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's nostalgia for reverse polish notation desk calculators, but I'd use `dc` rather than `bc` here:

```
dc <<<"2 k $cost_in_cents 100 / p"
```

Output is, properly, a float (with two digits past the decimal point of precision).

The exact same code, with no changes whatsoever, will work to convert `20` to `.20`.

---

See [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) for a full discussion on floating-point math in bash.

Comment: Love "dc" solutions :)

Answer (score 4):

Bash itself could not process floats.

It can, however, `printf` them:

```
$ printf 'value: %06.2f\n' 23.45
value: 023.45
```

So, you need an external program to do the math:

```
$ echo "scale=4;2345/100*20/100" | bc
4.6900
```

Or, equivalent:

```
$ bc <<<"scale=4;2345*20/10^4"
4.6900
```

Then, you can format the float with printf:

```
$ printf 'result: %06.2f\n' $(bc <<<"scale=4;2345*20/10^4")
result: 004.69
```

Or you can use a program that can process floats; like `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
read -p "What is the total cost? " input
percent=20
echo "scale=2; $input / 100 * $percent / 100" | bc

# input = 2345 , output = 4.69
```